# Mobile Phone Design - Data Tables

Tags: mobile, interface-design, user-experience, tables

Currently I am struggling a bit with how to show a lot of data properly and user friendly on a mobile device.

On a website its easy to implement a table. You can show for example 7 columns. But having a table with 7 columns on a mobile device is not really user friendly. The data in the grid will have to wrap the words in order to show 7 columns next to each other.

- So what is a recommended way to show data on a mobile device which you usually shows in a table on larger screens?
- Do I need to use tables or are there much better approaches to show a lot of data.

  - for example split up in multiple screens?
  - expandable containers?
  - ??
- Can you give me some references where to look at actual designs
- Do I need to take into account different designs due to I am working on Android, Windows Phone and iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way to show data on a phone is reorder all the data from columns to rows.
You can find several libraries to do that, just search for "responsive tables".

For example "reflow" 
[Table: Reflow](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/tables/table-reflow.html)

And just for a reference , you can also read this:
[10+ Solutions for Responsive Data Tables](http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns)

Regarding the different platforms, yes, you should stick to them as much as you can.It's not mandatory,but it's good for the user. Just take a look to every single official website ( Material Design, iOs8, Windows Mobile ) and see how they show tables and lists.

Comment: +1 you may also like to look @ http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

Comment: One of the links in the answer is dead